# How do I use two different audio file in HTML? How can i select one of them with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering how It would be possible to declare multiple audio files and give them different IDs to then create JavaScript functions to make them play or stop.

I have a code, which will trigger a song through some buttons: the onclick functions for those buttons is to refer to an audio tag with the source as being the filename of the song. 
I created a couple of JavaScript functions to manage the button clicks, and everything works properly. 
Under the buttons, I placed some text which I want to trigger an audio-description of always by declaring the audio file through the audio tag, but it is not possible to insert two audio elements at once.
How could I declare more audio files and then select them through ID in the JavaScript code?
Here is the code:

```html
<body  id="body">
<pre>

<p style="font-size:15px;font-family:Courier New;">Ain't No Mountain High Enough</p>
<button onclick="PlaySound(this)">Play</button> <button onclick="StopSound()">Stop</button>
<audio id='mountain' src="somefile.mp3"/>
<audio id="test" src="someotherfile.mp3"/>
</pre>
<div style="font-size:15px;">
<p>Hover over the following Text to hear an Audiodescription.</p>
<p onclick="test()">Test</p>
</div>
<script>
// All the Sound Options
  function PlaySound() {
    var thissound=document.getElementById("mountain");
    thissound.play();
  }

  function StopSound() {
    var thissound=document.getElementById("mountain");
    thissound.pause();
    thissound.currentTime = 0;
  }
 
  function test() {
 var test=document.getElementById("test");
    test.play(); 
  }
</script>
</body>
```

When writing this post I couldn't find any sound files to reproduce, so the snippet won't play any sound either, edit this code on your end so that you can specify files that are existing for you. 
When I ran this code on my end, the "Ain't no Mountain High Enough" song would play and stop, but the text wouldn't trigger anything. 
If I removed the "Ain't no Mountain High Enough" audio tag, then the text would finally trigger the function and work properly. 
- Is there an answer to this with simple code?

Comment: So all you need is to insert an `<audio>` tag in the page and address it later on? Why do you need an ID for that? I assume you already have the `<audio>` element after creating it. It’s not really clear what exactly you need help with. What have you researched to solve this? What do you mean by _“the text wouldn’t trigger anything”_? Have you used the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors?

Comment: I noticed that if I insert two different audio tags the browser doesn't support it, therefore I can just use one audio source. I need to use a lot of different audio sources, so how can I do?
(what i'm trying to say is that the browser doesn't support 2 different audio tags, so how can I source 2 different audiofiles and then play / pause them through JavaScript)